# Points equidistant from three lines .

Tags: geometry

If L1 , L2 and L3 are three non-concurrent and nonparallel lines in 2-dimesional plane , then maximum number of points which are equidistant from all the three lines is/are ?

This question stumped me and I have no approach to this question at all . People claim it to be 2 but spoiler ……… the answer is 4 . The topic is coordinate geometry . I can see it forms a triangle , therefore the orthocentre is the one of the answer if I am not wrong . But I can’t think of anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4 points in particular are the incenter and the 3 excenters of the triangle formed by the lines.

Note that for a point to be equidistant to 3 lines, the perpendiculars from this point to all 3 lines must be congruent. This suggests that we only need to consider the centers of circles that are tangent to the 3 lines. These are, of course, the incenter and excenters.

Comment: Yes mate - you’re right I didn’t think about the excentres and kept worrying about points in the interior of the triangle . Thanks for the help !